# Execute SQL prepared statement in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, chart.js

I can successfully create a graph through Chart.js. The issue is that I would like to generate a graph based on a specific customer's ID. So for example if I were to visit customer http://localhost/test/view_customer?customer_id=21&operation=edit. I would like use the bdi vs. date of customer ID 21 to generate a graph.

I have tried many different solutions, however I have been unsuccessful. I wanted to know if there was anyway to execute an SQL request through AJAX and use that data to generate a graph.

Here is my SQL code that grabs the ID from the URL and generates a string that could be read by chart.js to create a line graph:

```html
<?php
//Gets customer ID from URL 
$cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']);
//query to get data from the table
$sql = sprintf("SELECT treatment_log.bdi, treatment_log.date FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ? ORDER BY created_at");

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $cid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$data = array();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bdi, $date);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
  $data[] = array('bdi' => $bdi, 'date' => $date);
}
//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data); ?>
```

Here is the code I use to generate a line graph:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/test/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var bdi = [];
      var date = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        date.push( data[i].date);
        bdi.push(data[i].bdi);
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: date,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'BDI',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(239, 243, 255, 0.75)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(84, 132, 255, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',

            data: bdi
          }
        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata,
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',

          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                fontStyle: "bold",
                beginAtZero: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 5,
                padding: 20
              },
              gridLines: {
                drawTicks: false,
                drawBorder: false,

              }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                display: false
              },
              ticks: {
                padding: 20,
                fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                fontStyle: "bold"
              }
            }]
          },

          tooltips: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255)',
            titleFontColor: 'rgb(184,189,201)',
            bodyFontColor: 'black',
            displayColors: false,
            borderColor: 'rgb(214,217,225)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            caretSize: 5,
            cornerRadius: 2,
            xPadding: 10,
            yPadding: 10
          }
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Currently I am using a URL http://localhost/test/data.php that has a string of data:

```
[{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-11"},{"bdi":"1","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"5","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-22"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-24"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-25"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"11","date":"2018-07-30"}]
```

Instead of using a URL to link the data. I want the AJAX to run my SQL code and generate the graph (where the treatment_fk is a variable).

Question:

**1. Is it possible to execute an SQL command in AJAX to generate a graph, where the ID is a variable collected from the URL?** (How would I do this?)

**2. Is there a better way? How would I do that?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178237/discussion-on-question-by-james-execute-sql-prepared-statement-in-ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple one addition parameter to ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    data: { 
        "ChartType": 1/*Or change to drop down selection id*/,
        "customer_id":1
    },
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {

    }
});
```

You can see `ChartType` above, pass its value dynamically for which your want to separate sql query/

Now on server side:

```
$cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']);
$cType = htmlentities ($_GET['ChartType']);

if($cType==1)
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT treatment_log.bdi, treatment_log.date FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ? ORDER BY created_at");
else if($cType==2)
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT __ other column name __ WHERE cid=$cid");
else 
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT __ other column name __ WHERE cid=$cid");
```

I know this is not complete code, but it will give you idea how to do it.

Comment: I see, how about send the data back?

Comment: You echo the results from the query in whatever format you need.Those results will be available in `response`.